# Flipping an SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG But for some reason it is upside down . This SVG has some styling applied but it doesn't suppose to flip it . The  styling i have applied on the SVG :

```
" transform=scale(0.00800);
fill="#404952" ;
stroke="#fff" ;
stroke-width='20' ;
transform-origin: center;
transform-box: fill-box;
transition: linear;
transition-duration: 1000ms;
"
```

I did a quick search and found out that the solution is supposed to be as simple as adding

```
"transform= rotate(0.5turn)"
```

( or 'deg' units ) or in my case since i already use transform -

```
transform= scale(0.00800) rotate(0.5turn)
```

but unfortunately not only it doesn't work for me , it also canceled the effect of the 'scale' .

i'm not sure why this is happening , but if you have any suggestions / solutions i will be glad to try them out .

edit : Sorry , I know the way I have typed the styling might be confusing or wrong . Let me explain : I am using 'styled Components' for the tranistion & transform stuff (execpt scale). The other props i pass at the jsx element itself so it kinda looks like this :
`<svg > <g fill="someColor"> ....</g></svg>`  , thats why the syntax at my post is kinda mixed up .

Comment: This question has nothing to do with React. Removing React-related tags & "React" from title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of css

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform:rotateX(180deg); 180 or - 180 // if not working add 
perspective:800px; //change this 800px
```

Comment: U can change them to react styling

Comment: Just like in js element.style.___ = __;

Comment: this have worked for me , thank you so much ! 
could you explain what the 'perspective:800px;' do ?

Comment: Well just like u r sitting front of tv and distance is the perspective change it u will see effect

Comment: Play with this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.php?filename=playcss_perspective

Answer (score 0):

If this is under `<style>...</style>`, try using `property: value` instead of `property = value`

So your transform CSS should be like so instead:

```css
transform: scale(0.00800) rotate(0.5turn);
```

If this is under an inline SVG attribute, try add a quote around it like so:

```xml
<svg>
<g transform="scale(0.00800) rotate(0.5turn)">...</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry , I know the way I have typed the styling might be confusing or wrong . Let me explain :
 I am using 'styled Components' for the tranistion & transform stuff (execpt scale).
The other props i pass at the jsx element itself so it kinda looks like this :
``` <svg > <g fill="someColor> ....</g></svg> ```  , thats why the syntax at my post is kinda mixed up .

Comment: I see that makes sense. Try adding quote around the value of transform (I am going to edit the answer to clarify this).